# MOODLE - custom CSS for blocks

Tags: css, moodle

I want to create custom css for my custom block content, but moodle will take css from theme for all the blocks with similar css:

```
.block div.content {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px 15px 15px;
}
```

Here is the code I added to my blocks/status/styles.css:

```
.block_status .footer { margin-top: 5px; }
.block_status .content { border:1px dotted green; overflow:hidden; padding:0px; }
.block_status div.cname { border:1px solid blue;padding:10px; }
```

My css wasn't working. How could we create a new custom css for my block content. I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moodle CSS data is automatically minimized and combined into a single file, so that it can be downloaded more quickly by the end user.

If you are making changes to the stylesheets, you either need to turn on [Theme Designer Mode](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme#Theme_designer_mode) or purge all caches (Site admin > Development > Purge all caches), before the changes are visible.

Comment: Hi Davosmith, thank you for your kind help. I turned on designer mode and purged too, but I didn't get any change. I need to execute my custom css for my block_status. Is there any other solution

Comment: Assuming you have targeted the CSS correctly and you have purged the caches, then there isn't any other solution - that is the correct way to implement it. Have you used the Chrome developer tools to check which CSS rules are being applied to the elements? Often these problems are the result of a rule that is being overridden by other, more specific CSS rules.

Comment: I have a same problem when i created my first plugin on moodle and used this approach its working for me .... Thanks

Comment: you can purge cache from command line too : `php admin/cli/purge_caches.php`. This is handy while developing.

Comment: Purging the cache helped me when I incremented the value of `$plugin->version`, so Moodle has reloaded the entire plugin (and saw the styles.css I guess). Hope this helps someone.